# Jira REST API get last issues

Tags: jira

My application should execute some logic each time new issue is added to Jira. I guess the only option for me is to request last added issues every n seconds and find out which issues are new. I am investigating [Jira REST API](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+REST+APIs) but can't find there any method for retrieving last issues. Is it possible?

Comment: Execute a JQL query via REST to find all issues updated in the last minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do something similar, eventually I used the [Jira Scripting Suite](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jss) since it was easier. I've added a Jython post function to "Create issue" transition.

This way, any time a new issue will be added, your script will run.
Does it answer your needs?

Comment: Actually yes, it does. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

you could try consuming the activity feed from Jira. This page outlines the url to access it and to filter it to match your search criteria https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/consuming-an-activity-streams-feed/

Answer (score 3):

For your polling based solution, you can query the "Search" method in Jira REST API with JQL.

POST to:

```
http://[yourjirainstance]/rest/api/2/search
```

With sdata query in body:

```
{"jql" : "project = MyProject and updated>=2012-09-01",
                 "startAt" : 0,
                 "maxResults" : 50
}
```

This way you can do queries that you would normally do on the Jira interface.
Check [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching#AdvancedSearching-FieldsReference) for reference of fiels you can use in queries.

Needless to say but don't forget "Content-Type: application/json" in the headers and workout authentication if the session is not already authenticated.